# MySql try to get information from table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I stack on this error for a long time, I try to find some records by passing the where condition with variable. for some reason the query code that I wrote in python those  not  get the variable and return this error :

self._connection.handle_unread_result().

raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found").

mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.

and here is the code I am using to function to execute!

```
def unfollow_user(username, update):
    if update == True:
        get_list_of_not_following_back()

    sql.cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM not_following_back  WHERE username = (%s) AND of_user = 
                    (%s)",(username, current_user[0]))
    unfollow_user_id = sql.cur.fetchone()

def unfollow_number_of_follower():
    sql.cur.execute("SELECT username,user_id FROM not_following_back WHERE of_user =(%s)", 
                   (current_user[0],))
    list_of_user_to_unfollow = sql.cur.fetchmany(number_of_user_to_unfollow)

    for each_user_to_unfollow in list_of_user_to_unfollow:
        unfollow_user(each_user_to_unfollow[0], False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the result to this problem all you need to do is defined your cur as

```
cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```

I am not sure why but it work